# error: method until in class FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types; Appium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I have got this compilation error when running my test cases.
I have recently upgraded the selenium jar to 3.9.0 and then the compilation has stopped. I dont know if there is any other dependency that I am not fulfilling

```
WaitUntil.shortWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   required: Function<? super WebDriver,V>
    [javac]   found: ExpectedCondition<Alert>
    [javac]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
    [javac]     (argument mismatch; ExpectedCondition<Alert> cannot be converted to Function<? super WebDriver,V>)
    [javac]   where V,T are type-variables:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in method <V>until(Function<? super T,V>)
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class FluentWait

    public static boolean isAlertPresent(){
            boolean foundAlert = false;
            //      FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(Actions.getDriver(), 2 /*timeout in seconds*/);
            try {
                WaitUntil.shortWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

                foundAlert = true;
                System.out.println("Alert found");
            } catch (TimeoutException eTO) {
                foundAlert = false;
                System.out.println("Alert not found");
            }
            return foundAlert;
        }
```

[These are the libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3raT.png)

Can someone please help with this...

Comment: Please provide the full strack trace. Please point out to the line in your code snippet, which the stack trace is mentioning (a simple comment like /* This is line 123 */ is fine)

Comment: Can you take out some time to segregate the error stack trace and your code block for a proper analysis? You seem to have mixed up the concept of _WebDriverWait_ and _FluentWait_ . Go the JavaDocs of [_WebDriverWait_](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [_FluentWait_](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) .

Comment: Check the version of the guava jar. ExepctedCondition still expects the guava Function interface instead of the Java 8 one... Refer to this link for more details -- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
    </dependency>
```